# Javascript validate allow submit even if there an Error

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form with Javascript validation for various fields. However, whenever I submit the form, the error messages I've added appear even if the form fields are correct (i.e. not empty or null).

I'd like the error message only to appear when the form fields are empty or null.

```
    <html lang="en-US">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.1,shrink-to-fit=no">
         <link type="text/css" href="/css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
           <title>Javascript Form Validation</title>
            <style>
             </style>
              </head>
               <body>
                <div class="container">
                 <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                   <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName1">Full name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName1" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div> 
    <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>

<script>

    class User
            {
            constructor(userName,submitButton)
                {
                this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;
                this.submitButton = document.getElementById("myForm");
                }
            submitForm()
                {
                this.submitButton.onsubmit = function()
                    {
                    if(this.userName == "" || this.userName == null)
                        {
                        document.write("Name Required");
                        return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    let user = new User();
    user.submitForm();
</script>
```

Comment: Cleaned up language and code

Comment: I cleaned up your post because some of your code was hidden. The best way to make sure that code isn't hidden is to highlight all of the code and click the `{}` icon when you are composing your question.

Answer (score 0):

This line inside the class constructor

```
this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;
```

The value of this.userName would go stale as soon as you type the username so it is always blank.

You should move that line from the constructor and place it as shown below:

```
this.submitButton.onsubmit = function()
{
    this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;
```

**OR**

You could *ideally* do it like this:

```
class User
{
    constructor(userName,submitButton)
    {
        this.userName = document.myForm.name;  /* remove .value here */
        this.submitButton = document.getElementById("myForm");
    }
    submitForm()
    {
        this.submitButton.onsubmit = function()
        {
            if(this.userName.value == "" || this.userName.value == null) /* add .value here */
            {
                document.write("Name Required");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've added comments on 2 x lines that have changed.